# How to create a new Table using Table Storage in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have tried to use the samples that Roger Jennings recommeded in his book, "Cloud Computing with Windows Azure", but he is using version 1.  I'm using v1.2 and there is a lot of differences.  Firstly, I had to recompile the StorageClient DLL with the corrected namespace and other changes.  Then, when I use his code to create a Table at the application start, I get an "out of range index".

Has anyone managed to successfully create a Table at application startup?  If so, how?  Also, if there are any tutorials/samples that use version 1.2, I'd greatly appreciate them too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You no longer have to rebuild the sample storage client library. v1.2 will automagically add three DLL references to your role:

- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics
- Microsoft.WindowAzure.ServiceRuntime
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient

To create a table, you'll need to first set up your table :

- Create a class deriving from TableServiceEntity (say, "MyEntity")-
- Derive a table class from TableServiceContext (say, "MyEntityDataServiceContext"). In that class, create a property of type DataServiceQuery < MyEntity >() that returns CreateQuery < MyEntity > ("MyEntities");

Once you've done that, create the table with code like this:

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
CloudTableClient.CreateTablesFromModel(typeof(MyEntityDataServiceContext),account.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, account.Credentials);
```

For a much more detailed look at this, download the [Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en). There's a lab called "Exploring Windows Azure Storage" that covers all this.

Comment: +1: Just for the word "automagically" :o)  Will let you know how I get on.  Thanks for the answer.